# Remove unwanted entries from Legend in pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, legend, boxplot

I am trying to combine a box-plot with the actual points to show distribution. Furthermore, the marks used for the points depend on whether the treatment it represents was positive (marked x) or neutral (marked triangle).

Here is my minimal working code with mock data:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
every y tick label/.append style={font=\footnotesize},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\footnotesize},
xmode=log,
yticklabel style={align=center},
ytick={1,2},
yticklabels={Diabetes, Cancer},
boxplot/box extend=0.48,
xlabel={CFU/day},
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.17)},anchor=north,legend cell align=left, draw=none},
%
scatter/classes={%
    a={mark=triangle,draw=black},
    b={mark=x,draw=blue}}]
%
%
\addplot+ [% AAD:
boxplot prepared={
lower whisker= 430000, lower quartile= 1126500015.5,
median= 10000000000,
upper quartile= 34000000000, upper whisker= 60000000000},
black, solid, thick, no marks] coordinates {};
%
\addplot[scatter,only marks,%
    scatter src=explicit symbolic]%
table[y index=0, x index=1,meta=label] {
y x label
1   14500000000 a
1   51000000000 a
1   17000000000 a
1   210000000   a
1   4500000000  a
1   430000  a
1   400000000   a
1   4000000000  a
1   60000000000 b
1   50000000000 b
1   50000000000 b
1   1450000000  b
1   803000031   b
1   10000000000 b
1   18000000000 b
};
%
\addplot+ [% Cancer:
boxplot prepared={
lower whisker= 300000000, lower quartile= 8975000000,
median= 17650000000,
upper quartile= 26325000000, upper whisker= 35000000000},
black, solid, no marks] coordinates {};
%
\addplot[scatter,only marks,%
    scatter src=explicit symbolic]%
table[y index=0, x index=1,meta=label] {
y x label
2   300000000   b
2   35000000000 b
2   15000000000 a
};
\legend{Positive, Neutral}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the output:

[image: Box_plot_problem]

As you can see, the legend is wonky. I want the legend to only show the points demarcating `x` and `triangle`. I want it to ignore  the boxplot in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you looking for something like this:

[image]

(I took a liberty and change color of marks and legend position, but this you can easily change according to your wish)

For this result you need to change order of `\addplot` macros, first two are for `scatter plot`, last two for `boxplot`. Between them is command `\legend`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[
every tick label/.append style={font=\footnotesize},
ytick={1,2},
yticklabels={Diabetes, Cancer},
xlabel={CFU/day},
legend pos=outer north east,
%
scatter/classes={%
    a={mark=triangle,draw=red},
    b={mark=x,draw=blue}}]
%
\addplot[scatter, only marks,%
         scatter src=explicit symbolic]%
table[y index=0, x index=1,meta=label] {
y   x           label
1   14500000000 a
1   51000000000 a
1   17000000000 a
1   210000000   a
1   4500000000  a
1   430000      a
1   400000000   a
1   4000000000  a
1   60000000000 b
1   50000000000 b
1   50000000000 b
1   1450000000  b
1   803000031   b
1   10000000000 b
1   18000000000 b
};
%
\addplot[scatter, only marks,%
         scatter src=explicit symbolic]%
table[y index=0, x index=1, meta=label] {
y   x           label
2   300000000   b
2   35000000000 b
2   15000000000 a
};
\legend{Positive, Neutral}
%
\addplot[% AAD:
boxplot prepared={
lower whisker= 430000, lower quartile= 1126500015.5,
median= 10000000000,
upper quartile= 34000000000, upper whisker= 60000000000},
black, no marks] coordinates {};

\addplot[% Cancer:
boxplot prepared={
lower whisker = 300000000,   lower quartile= 8975000000, median= 17650000000,
upper quartile= 26325000000, upper whisker = 35000000000},
black, no marks] coordinates {};
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```